# How to get data from $.parseJSON(data)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to get data through ajax the code is working fine before call `$.parseJSON(data)` but show empty object when i call the `$.parseJSON(data)`. here is my code.

```
success: function(data){
        //alert(data);//working fine here
        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(result); //issue is here. }
```

[image]

The output of `console.log(result);` is:

```
[{"pkjobid":"13","fkuserid":"42","companyname":"Testing Company","jobtitle":"Testing Vr","startdate":"Mar 2016","enddate":"Dec 2016","jobdescription":"verime testing","jobstatus":"1","created_date":"2016-12-07","update‌​d_date":null}]
```

Comment: Did you ever console it? if you did it please show the console

Comment: `[object Object]` is not an empty response

Comment: a empty object is `{}`

Comment: Thanks @Sudharsan S: Yah i console it.let me show the console response.

Comment: which jquery version you used ?

Comment: What is the result of console.log()

Comment: @Sudharsan S console response: [{"pkjobid":"13","fkuserid":"42","companyname":"Testing Company","jobtitle":"Testing Vr","startdate":"Mar 2016","enddate":"Dec 2016","jobdescription":"verime testing","jobstatus":"1","created_date":"2016-12-07","updated_date":null}]

Comment: @Sudharsan S:  jQuery v3.1.1

Comment: Please make sure As of jQuery 3.0, $.parseJSON is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use the native JSON.parse method instead.

Comment: Let me try @Sudharsan S.

Comment: @Sudharsan S: Tried but same response.

Comment: what value you try to get?

Comment: if you want pkjobid value console,log(result[0].pkjobid);

Comment: @HazratBilal - what value you want to get it for the result response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your context use `JSON.parse(result)`;

You are using jquery version 3.1.1. As of jQuery 3.0, $.parseJSON is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use the native JSON.parse method instead.

Comment: Tried but not resolve my issue.Thanks for your response

Comment: @HazratBilal - if you alert(result) it will prints like [object, object] if you wan print the particular value in the array object alert(result[0].pkjobid) some thing like that. now the alert gives correct

Answer (score 0):

Its not an empty response, it contains an objects, you are not able to see it properly because the `toString()` method of it is not available.

```
Try console.log(result) and open the console to check out the result
```

Comment: this does not qualify as an answer

Comment: @Upesh M console.log(result) working fine but when i alert(result) then show me that error.

Comment: @HazratBilal Why do you think it's an error? That's what you see when you convert an object to a string, and `alert()` requires its argument to be a string.

Comment: @ Barmar - sorry but i am new in js so that's why i called it error.